# Are "SOCKS5 proxying" and "ssh tunneling" same thing?

Tags: ssh, proxy, openssh, socks

1. I know that I can run a socks5 proxy by `ssh -D some-port-number remote-server-url`.
2. I know that I can configure my applications (for example firefox) to use socks5 proxy (often by specifying something like `socks5://localhost:that-port-number-metioned-above`).
3. I hear people online referring to this technique as "socks5 proxy" or "ssh tunneling"; sometimes I even see people talking about "reverse ssh tunnling".
4. But as far as I know socks5 and ssh are totally different protocols, the only similarity between them is that they both have server-client architecture. Reading wiki definitions and googling on these concepts didn't clarify my confusion..

So how are these concepts -- `SOCKS5 proxying`, `ssh tunneling`, `reverse ssh tunneling` related with each other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you describe is a SOCKS proxy. It is standalone protocol used by various tools. What `openssh` does it to tunnel this protocol encrypted from one point to the other. But more precisely, it is called TCP port forwarding (it forwards one port from client through the secure tunnel to the server).

There are other possibilities to use TCP port forwarding in `openssh` using `-L` and `-R` switches that are correctly named Local ("brings" remote service to local host) and Remote (makes local service accessible from remote host).

As you can see, there are similarities, but they are implemented in different way. All of them are TCP port forwarding (through secure tunnel). The Dynamic (`-D`) special, because the server have to understand the SOCKS protocol.

Comment: Reading your answer plus rereading wikipedia page on ssh tunneling plus rereading ubuntu wiki page on ssh port forwarding plus rereading ssh man page on -L -R -D plus rereading this(http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115897/whats-ssh-port-forwarding-and-whats-the-difference-between-ssh-local-and-remot) post finally makes sense to me!

Comment: One more question: I know that SSH and SOCKS are totally different two separate protocols but.. Does openssh use SOCKS protocol for its -D option because SOCKS protocol is somehow related to SSH protocol? (maybe both are drafted by same author) Or openssh just happens to use SOCKS for that because SOCKS does the job?

Comment: No, the socks is used in SSH because it is somehow standard protocol used by other applications. You can use SOCKS in most of the browsers, but also system-wide in Linux, AFAIK